# Facebook Share iOS Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook sharing SDK in my iOS app.

I followed the steps in the Facebook Developer Website. But I have an issue, the problem is that Facebook is not showing the app name on posts published by my app as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

and I have some errors in the logs :

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbapi20150629:/" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fbapi20150629"
>
> plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated

but the photo is shared without any issue, the only problem is that there is not the app name on the post shared.

But when sharing a ContentLink I see the app name on the post, it doesn't work on photos !!

here is my code to share in iOS :

```
let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
let content: FBSDKSharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
let photo: FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = image
photo.userGenerated = true
content.photos = [photo]
FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: nil)
```

info.plist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>fr_FR</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.3.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>

    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>master_of_break.otf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb100967589******</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>100967589******</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>Athéna</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Post shared with app name (it works on Android )

[image]

Comment: please share your info.plist file

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Social Framework to implement this ? Its very easy to implement and displays text, url , photo .

You just have to follow the below steps :-
1) Goto your app -> Build phases

2) Click on Link Binary with Libraries and add Social framework

3) In your View Controller import `<Social/Social.h>`

4) In your sharing action write the below code :-

```
if  SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook)
{
    let fbShare = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    fbShare.setInitialText("Swift programming")
    fbShare.addURL(NSURL(string: filePath)) 
    fbShare.addImage(UIImage(named:"ImageName")) 

    self.presentViewController(fbShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Else you can follow the  below link for integration :-

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/facebook-integration-using-swift

To show your app link refer this  :-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios

Answer (score 0):

Add the following items to your info.plist

[image]